# How to add request headers when uploading a file using iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, iframe

My form should upload a file and it should work with older versions of IE. That's why I use a hidden iframe. The thing is that I need to add a couple of headers to the request as they are required by the 3rd party API that I'm using. How to set the request headers when using an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

XMLHttpRequest is the only API which browsers provide that allows that setting of HTTP headers from JavaScript.